# Improving AI Image Upscale

Tags: python, image-processing, artificial-intelligence, resolution

I would like to improve the resolution of images using AI upscaling, but the 4 different SR models supported in python are nowhere near as good as online websites. For example, here is the original image:

[image]

The best performing model (EDSR) using this code results in this:

```
sr = dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()
image = cv2.imread('Images/exported_image_76322.png')
path = "EDSR_x3.pb"
sr.readModel(path)
sr.setModel("edsr", 3)
result = sr.upsample(image)
cv2.imwrite('ai_upscale.png', result)
display_image_in_actual_size('ai_upscale.png')
```

[image]

Websites such as zyro.com produce much nicer results:

[image]

How can I improve my results so that they are the same level of quality as the ai upscale websites? I want to automate the upscaling of hundreds of images so simply using the websites is not feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different options:

1. If you have original hi-res images, you can take an online model and finetune (i.e. continue training it) on your hi-res images (output= hi-res image, input=low-res image). This is the best solution because your model will be training on the correct data distribution.
2. If you don't have access to original hi-res images, but you believe that zyro provides adequate quality for your purpose, you can create a dataset using zyro and finetune an existing SR model on that dataset.
3. If you have hi-res images which are not of your dataset you could finetune your existing SR model on those (lower their resolution and train your model to recover the hi-res), and see if it generalizes well to your dataset.

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately I do not have any hi-res originals, so I would have to go with option 2. How would I go about finetuning an existing model? I can not seem to find anything useful. Thanks

Comment: Here is a tutorial on how to do this: 
You will be able to load an existing model and then refine it on whatever dataset you want:  https://github.com/sgrvinod/a-PyTorch-Tutorial-to-Super-Resolution

Comment: I also have a feeling that if you just load the SRGAN pretrained model from the above tutorial, it should be as good if not better than zyro.

Comment: I dont see how I can simply use a pretrained model. Everything that I see requires a training of a model myself.

Comment: Also, do I use the zyro images to train? Or are you saying that the pretrained models of SRGAN are sufficient and will yield better results than zyro?

Comment: You are right, they don't seem to have saved the trained weights in the repo. That's unfortunate. I would try training it exactly the way they do it first. See how that works, then, if it's not good enough at that point, you can add the zyro images to train on. But first just train exactly as they do, and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV allows to download and import models.
To get started you can download a small open-source one from [here](https://github.com/Saafke/FSRCNN_Tensorflow/blob/master/models/FSRCNN_x2.pb)

```
import cv2
from cv2 import dnn_superres

# Create an SR object
sr = dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()

# Read image
image = cv2.imread('./input.png')

# Read the desired model
path = "FSRCNN_x2.pb"
sr.readModel(path)

# Set the desired model and scale to get correct pre- and post-processing
sr.setModel("edsr", 3)

# Upscale the image
result = sr.upsample(image)

# Save the image
cv2.imwrite("./upscaled.png", result)
```